# De-authorizing a twitter OAuth application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, twitter, oauth-ruby

We just finished implementing OAuth in our RoR application using the [Twitter gem](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/). The whole authentication process works perfectly and we are able to persist access tokens. We're wondering if there's a way for our de-authorize our access to twitter via our website. I realize we could just destroy the persisted token, but I'd also like to be able to remove us from the [connections list](http://twitter.com/settings/connections) on twitter so the user gets the sense that we're totally disconnected from their account. We checked the [oauth-ruby](http://rdoc.info/projects/oauth/oauth-ruby) and [twitter rdocs](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) and couldn't find anything relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to possible vulnerabilities Twitter does not provide this API. Look at Raffi's response -

http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/64a49da760250d9/bfe896c156670692

But you can always direct the user to twitter/settings/connections and ask the user to revoke access to your app manually.

Comment: It would seem sending the user to Twitter is the best bet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same issue here. I've studied to Twitter docs, and the best I could come up with is just to throw away the token. There doesn't seem to be any API for deauthorizing at the Twitter side.